# Centrar dos TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Quería saber como se puede hacer para centrar dos textview, dentro de un ConstraintLayout, he usado gavity y text alignment en los textos pero sin ningún resultado

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenedorTotal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/total_background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textoTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Total: "
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrecio"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/precioTexto"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Imagen de visualización]

Comment: aqui una guia como usar contraint layout https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout  . Para centar solo tienes que  meterlos los 2 en un linera layout horizontal,  y el linear layout centrarlo en el contraint layout es facil solo poner todos sus lados apunten a cada lado del padre , pero este tiene que tener tamaño y ancho para q no se estire.

Comment: Puedes usar dos textView, el primero constraintStartStart al parent, consEndStart text2, y el textView 2 constraintStartEnd textView1 y constraintEndEnd parent... de todas formas puedes usar sólo un textview con un string dinámico y spannable o usar un string html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas usando ConstraintLayout, android:gravity y android:textAlignment no son muy útiles, debes establecer restricciones, es importante estudies la documentación.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout?hl=es-419

Primeramente, imagino que total_background.xml es el borde redondeado que deseas, si no es así, deberías usar uno como este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- we define background color -->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <!-- we define border color and thick -->
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
    <!-- add some padding for text inside -->
    <padding
        android:bottom="15dp"
        android:left="15dp"
        android:right="15dp"
        android:top="15dp" />
    <!-- we define corner radius, note that radius can be different for each corner -->
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Este sería el layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/contenedorTotal"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/total_background" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="         Total: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPrecio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/precioTexto"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textoTotal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Para tener un resultado como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]